# How to integrate the mavon editor with nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, markdown, nuxt3

I am trying to use mavon-editor in my nuxt3 app using nuxt plugin. But I am unable to `<mavon-editor />` component in template.

**plugin**

```
import {mavonEditor} from 'mavon-editor';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
      provide: {
        mavonEditor
      }
    }
  })
```

**app.vue**

```
<script setup>
  const mavonEditor = useNuxtApp().$mavonEditor;
  console.log(mavonEditor) // getting data here
</script>


<template>
  <div>
    <mavon-editor />  
  </div>
</template>
```

There some blogs available for this but all of them are for Nuxt2.

**How can I use `<mavon-editor />` component in app.vue in Nuxt3?**

I have used this [mavonEditor doc](https://github.com/hinesboy/mavonEditor/blob/master/README-EN.md#:%7E:text=%3C/div%3E-,Use%20in%20nuxt.js,-new%20file%3A%20vue) as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.0.0-beta must be used.

For details checking out this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/modules/issues/676